# Magento 1.9 group price incorrectly calculated for simple products

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, catalog-price-rules

We appear to have an issue with customer group pricing discounts on simple products. We have a 25% discount customer group with the following configuration in 'Catalog Price Rules':

[image: Catalog Price Rules]

This appears to be correctly calculated in admin

[image: Product price tab]

But in the front end, *only for simple products*, we are not seeing the same  price

[image: Simple product front end]

As you can see here, configurable product options are ok

[image: Configurable product price tab]
[image: Configurable product option]

What could I possibly be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the 1st image photoshopped? Since I see double fields for discount % and how it's applied... or is the functionality extended by a custom module?

If I understand you correctly, you just want a 25% price reduction from the base price for the `customer group 25%`.

The problem with your configuration is that you are mixing 2 different types of discounts/prices: 1. Customer group price and 2. Catalog Rule Price for a customer group.

Since you set the `Enable discount to subproducts = Yes` it means the Catalog rule price discount will be used for simple products which are assigned to a configurable product.

But it's important to note that the discount is actually applied on the associated simple product price difference which is configured on the configurable product:

[image]

(image taken from this site: http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/magento-catalog-price-rules/)

So most probably the calculation for the simple product in your example goes like this:

```
0.28 * 0.75 = 0.21 --> this is the customer group price which was manually set in admin

0.21 * 0.75 = 0.16 (rounded 0.1575) --> applied discount from catalog rule price
```

So you just need to remove the catalog rule price rule to get the desired amount.

If I misunderstood you, please be a bit more detailed.

Comment: Lez you appear to be on the right track because as soon as I disable the Catalog Price Rule the simple product's price is correctly calculated. The configurable one's however are not. What I need is a mix of the two. The reason I'm using the Catalog Price Rule is because that's what is generating the Customer Group pricing. Rather than doing this manually we want to rely on a price rule to handle this - I thought that was the  point of them. The first image is not photoshopped - that's standard Magento functionality. It's this part that applies the discount to the configurable option pricing.

Comment: By creating a second attribute set for simple products and a second Catalog Price Rule with 'Enable for subproducts' disabled, then adding conditions on each rule that require the relevant attribute set I now have the correct price calculation. Many thanks Lez - have 50 bounty points for taking the time to answer, pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: Cheers! Glad I could be of help